# Xpath query and time

Tags: xpath, time

**Hi, this is the content of my XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<mainNode>
    <sub time="08:00">
        <status id="2">On</status>
        <status id="3">Off</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="13:00">
        <status id="4">On</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="16:00">
        <status id="5">On</status>
        <status id="6">On</status>
        <status id="7">Off</status>
        <status id="8">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="20:00">
        <status id="4">Off</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="23:59">
        <status id="4">On</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
</mainNode>
```

**My program gets the current time:
if I get 15.59, I must retrieve all the status id of the next sub time (16.00):**

```
<sub time="16:00">
        <status id="5">On</status>
        <status id="6">On</status>
        <status id="7">Off</status>
        <status id="8">On</status>
    </sub>
```

**With a second XPath query I must get all the status id of the previous sub time (13.00).
How to do it? I know SQL but I'm quite new to XPath. I accept urls to serious XPath resources too, if any. Thanks!**

Comment: You ought to state your language platform and version of Xpath.  XPath 2.0 would make this easier but that may not be available to you.

Comment: You are perfectly right: we're talking about XPath 2.0.

Comment: I have provided two solutions in my answer: an XPath 1.0 and an XPath 2.0. +1 for the question!

Comment: @vyger Thanks for pointing this -- some weird bug in the "code" button. The indexes in the XSLT 2 code were shown as 7 and 8. Just edited it, if this continues, I will edit further and will not use the code button.

Comment: @vyger See: http://tinyurl.com/dd4tsy This is about XSLT books, but they cover by necessity XPath very well. My favourite is Michael Kay and his latest book on both XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0. BTW, if you think and answer is what you wanted, you can select it (click the check mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

## I. XPath 1.0

**This is one pair of [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) expressions** that select the required nodes:

```
/*/*
    [translate(@time, ':','') 
    > 
     translate('15:59',':','')
    ][1]
```

**selects the first `sub` node with time later than `15:59`.**

```
/*/*
    [translate(@time, ':','') 
    < 
     translate('15:59',':','')
    ][last()]
```

**selects selects the first `sub` node with the previous than `15:59` `sub` time**.

**We can include these in an XSLT transformation** and check that the really wanted result is produced:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      First time after 15:59: 
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/*
          [translate(@time, ':','') 
         > 
           translate('15:59',':','')
          ][1]
      "/>

      First time before 15:59: 
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/*
          [translate(@time, ':','') 
         &lt; 
           translate('15:59',':','')
          ][last()]
      "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied** on the originally provided XML document:

```
<mainNode>
    <sub time="08:00">
        <status id="2">On</status>
        <status id="3">Off</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="13:00">
        <status id="4">On</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="16:00">
        <status id="5">On</status>
        <status id="6">On</status>
        <status id="7">Off</status>
        <status id="8">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="20:00">
        <status id="4">Off</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
    <sub time="23:59">
        <status id="4">On</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
    </sub>
</mainNode>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
  First time after 15:59: 


<sub time="16:00">
        <status id="5">On</status>
        <status id="6">On</status>
        <status id="7">Off</status>
        <status id="8">On</status>
</sub>

  First time before 15:59: 

 <sub time="13:00">
        <status id="4">On</status>
        <status id="7">On</status>
 </sub>
```

**Do note** the following:

1. **The use of the XPath [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) function** to get rid of the colons
2. **The use of the [`last()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-last) function** in the second expression
3. **There is no need to convert the time to seconds** before the comparison
4. When used as part of an XML document (such as an XSLT stylesheet, **the `<` operator must be escaped**.

## II. XPath 2.0

**In [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) we can use the following two expressions** to produce select the desired nodes:

```
/*/*[xs:time(concat(@time,':00')) 
    gt 
     xs:time('15:59:00')
    ][1]
```

**selects the first `sub` node with time later than `15:59`.**

```
/*/*[xs:time(concat(@time,':00')) 
   lt 
     xs:time('15:59:00')
    ][last()]
```

**selects selects the first `sub` node with the previous than `15:59` `sub` time**.

**We can include these in an XSLT 2.0 transformation** and check that the really wanted result is produced:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      First time after 15:59: 
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/*[xs:time(concat(@time,':00')) 
           gt 
             xs:time('15:59:00')
             ][1]
      "/>

      First time before 15:59: 
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/*[xs:time(concat(@time,':00')) 
           lt 
             xs:time('15:59:00')
          ][last()]
      "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied** on the originally provided XML document (the same as in the first solution), the same wanted result is produced.

**Do note** the following:

1. **In XPath 2.0 [`xs:time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#time) is a native data type**. However, in order to construct an `xs:time()` from the values in the xml document, we have to concat to them the missing seconds part.
2. **In XPath 2.0 `xs:time` values can be compared with the "[atomic-value comarison operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#comp.duration.datetime)"** such as `lt` or `gt`.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, why that 2 here?

 [translate(@time, ':','') 
    > 
     translate('15:59',':','')
    ][2]

Comment: @vyger Thanks for pointing this -- some weird bug in the "code" button. The indexes in the XSLT 2 code were shown as 7 and 8. Just edited it, if this continues, I will edit further and will not use the code button.

Comment: Dmitre, your solutions were really complete, sorry for pointing out that typo. The first one is the solution I was looking for: I imagined it could be done but eventually I did not know how. Thanks!   :-)   Could you suggest a good book about XPath?

Comment: @vyger See: http://tinyurl.com/dd4tsy
This is about XSLT books, but they cover by necessity XPath very well. My favourite is Michael Kay and his latest book on both XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0. BTW, if you think and answer is what you wanted, you can select it (click the check mark)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Thanks, SO is a very nice Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the ugly Xpath 1.0 solution:-

```
sub[number((substring-before(@time, ':')) * 60 + number(substring-after(@time, ':'))) &gt; 959][1]
```

Note 959 = 15 * 60 + 59 which I'm sure you can do in your calling code.

Give that node the previous node can be accessed as:-

```
preceding-sibling::sub[1]
```

However a pragmatic, common sense solution would be to load the XML data into a set of data structures and use a language more suited to this task to look the items up.

Comment: For an XPath solution, that's the way to go. It's not even especially ugly, IMHO. +1

Comment: I'll test this solution and the krosenvold one (this last sounds more interesting, expecially if it works)   :-)

Comment: @Tomalak: I must admit I was expecting it to be much uglier but you're right its not actually that bad.

Comment: No need to calculate the total seconds -- see my answer.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Anthony, is there a way to concat numbers as if they were strings? I could convert that 15:59 into 1559 and compare it with 1600.

Answer (score 1):

Well as long as the time is HH:MM something like the following should work:
(I must excuse my syntax since I'm just dabbling without running, consider this pseudo-xpath):

```
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"

//sub[fn:compare(@time,'12:59') > 0][1]/status
```

This should select all the elements where time is greater than 12:59 and then select the first of those elements.

You could also pass the value '12:59' as an e[xternal parameter](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables) into the xpath evaluation.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, I must try. The exact link to the compare function is http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-compare (very good explanation too)

Comment: It is simpler to just use "lt" and "gt" when comparing two xs:time values.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the xml yourself, you could change the way you store the time attribute using an integer value (ticks, for example), then you could do an easy numerical comparison using something like

```
//sub[@time > 1389893892]
```

Comment: I don't generate it myself and they don't want to change the way it is generated...